# How to stop an RxJava observable from emitting items. Tried to unsubscribe but it kept going

Tags: android, rx-java

In my code I create an observable and keep a reference to the subscription object.
When I start the app it prints all the numbers from 1 to 1000000
If I minimize the activity, I ubsubscribe from the subscription in `onPause`
However, the LogCat keeps printing numbers. How do I stop it from doing so?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Subscription printingNumbers;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        printingNumbers = Observable
                          .range(1, 500000)
                          .map(i -> i*2)
                          .subscribe(i -> System.out.println(i));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        printingNumbers.unsubscribe();
    }

}
```

Comment: I think that range returns all the values at one, and takes time for the log to display them aka. unsubscribe is working but there are alot of values to be printed out. Can you try with .interval ?

Comment: Yeah, this did it. So my ubsubcription works. However, how do I achieve the same effect as .range but without getting all values at once? BTW If you post this as the answer, I will accept it

Comment: You are synchronously consuming the range in your onCreate so it doesn't even get to pause and unsubscription.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Range returns all the values at once but takes time on the Log to visualize it. Interval will return values at given time, that way you can test your unsubscribe.

PS: I think you can combine range and interval to emiits value up to a limit at given interval, but not sure as im just learning RX